# Lambda unresolved reference python

Tags: python, tkinter, lambda

I was just following a youtube video and did exactly the same in pycharm. But i got multiple errors while running programm. One major error is Lambda, which says *Unresolved reference*

```
import tkinter

root = tkinter.Tk()
root.title("Calculator")

numInput = tkinter.Entry(root, width=40, borderwidth=5)
numInput.grid(row=0, column=0, columnspan=3, padx=20, pady=20)

def button_click(number):
    current = numInput.get()
    numInput.delete(0, END)
    numInput.insert(0, str(current) + str(number))

#Define Buttons

button_1 = tkinter.Button(root, text="1", padx=40, pady=20, command = Lambda: button_click(1))
```

and another error in last line:
',' or ')' expected

Thank you for sharing the solution and **error reason**.

Comment: It should be `lambda`, with small 'l': `command=lambda: button_click(1)`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
button_1 = tkinter.Button(root, text="1", padx=40, pady=20, command = lambda: button_click(1))
```

spelled 'lambda' with capital 'L', so python doesn't understand it